# What changes to DOM are made when MVC Validation triggers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, dom

I have a form in a modal window that is currently performing some validation.
(I am using ASP.NET MVC, JQuery UI, ajax forms, data annotations and unobtrusive is active)

When this validation triggers I have noticed so far that it does a few things:

1: my validation summary gets it's class changed from `.validation-summary-valid` to `.validation-summary-errors`

2: my invalid inputs have a class added to then called `.input-validation-error`

3: my validation messages get their class changed from `.field-validation-valid` to `.field-validation-error`

But there is something else that it is doing and I cant work out how it is tracking this.

I have a textbox that is required, before triggering the validation i can select inside this box, then select another box and the validation will be silent.

But as soon as i trigger the validation by clicking submit with an empty textbox, i can select the textbox and type something to remove the validation instantly, but if i then null it and select a different box this error is re-applied without re-submitting.

So my question is: what has changed, how does it know that I have attempted to submit already?

Answer (score 1):

When validate is called, it adds a class to each input/select that is supposed to be validated.  When the input/select is not valid it adds a class to the input/select:

```
class="input-validation-error"
```

When it is valid, it adds:

```
class="valid"
```

**Validation only fires on the control when you change the value, not when it loses focus.**

Validation fires on change, even before you submit the form.  Take a required textbox, add a value to it, and tab off ... then go back and remove that value, and you should see the textbox highlighted red.

Comment: You are correct, the trigger seems to be when the text box is changed. However im still a little confused. I select the text box it has no class, I tab off, still no class, i enter and remove value, it has error class. I then use JQuery to removed this class using a cancel button. I reopen the window, inspect the input and it has no class (as before) but despite this, tabbing off still caused the validation to kick in. How does it know?